# HTTP transport error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect in Soap ws client

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, webservice-client

In my JAR client that i developed, When trying to call a soap ws using jax-ws i got connection timeout exception, i want to know what can be the reasons that causes this exception.
I am using a remote wsdl, and server certificate for https that must be run in VM arguments.

```
   -Djavax.net.debug=all
   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=link to my certifacte
```

How can i run with this arguments? 
By adding them eclipse.ini file ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You likely can't or shouldn't use eclipse.ini and instead add it to your application servers configuration.  What Application server are you using, e.g. JBoss/Wildfly, Tomcat, GlassFish or WebSphere?  Also, a connection timeout usually indicates nothings listening on the port you're trying to connect to or a firewall problem.

Comment: i'm not using any server i'm working on a client of a remote soap ws using a client ssl certificate and i need to set those VM argument after installing client certificate

Comment: So it's a standalone class file or JAR that you're running from a command line/shell? Well, you'll be running from Eclipse initially but when you pass it along to someone else/the end user they'll be running it from the CLI or shell.  Just wanted to check - get the facts straight prior to providing an answer ;-)

Comment: the client is just a Jar that i launch from Eclipse after that he we be integrated into a batch but now i should test it from my Jar.

Comment: Let me know if that helps, if it doesn't let me know what I can elaborate further on.  If it gets you going - please be sure to accept the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Select you project from the Project Explorer Pane, generally on the left**
[image: Step 1]

**2. From the Run menu, depending on whether you want to just run it or debug it click either Run or Debug**
[image: Step 2]

**3. In left pane, select "Java Application and right click and click New"**
[image]

**4. Since you've already selected your project and it contains a "Main" class, it will default the Run/Debug configuration "Name" to the class name.  If you have multiple Main's, you may have to click the Search button or manually type in the package path and class name**
[image: Step 4]

**5. Enter your arguments under "VM arguments" as shown**
[image: Step 5]

**6. Click Apply, or Apply and the Run if you want to run it immediately**

Some notes, you'll likely need the full path to the keystore such as:

`-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\ADirectory\AnotherDirectory\FinalDirectoryThatContainsYourKeystore\TrustStore.jks`

`-Djavax.net.debug=all` - is going to turn on a MASSIVE amount of debug which if you're not used to reading it, it can be confusing.  If the connection works remove that line.  If the connection doesn't work - thats when all that debug is useful.

**Update**: to further troubleshoot HTTP connectivity problems, when at the heart of it thats what a SOAP request is, temporarily remove the `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and add the following instead:

`-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true`

`-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true`

`-Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true`

`-Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true`

This will show you the HTTP headers, response code, request and response body contents.  It will also show the URL you are trying to connect to.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer i did the same, i got some ssl log such as client certificate information (keyStore type, algorithm, keyStore provider ...) but i still got connection time out

Comment: You're very welcome.  From your dev laptop/computer can you telnet to that server's IP address and port?  If you cannot, then you may need to contact whose hosting that server and find out the correct IP address and port - it could be port 8443 as well.  If that doesnt work - talk to your Firewall team and see if it's getting blocked!

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help i tried to telnet the server host but it's blocked in the same port that you mentioned 8443 i should inform them i think. thnx again.

Comment: But i have one more question why i can reach the web service using SOAPUI using the same WSDL and not with my client JAR ?

Comment: And SOAP UI is of course running on the same dev machine as your eclipse project?  Yes, that wouldn't make much sense.  Whats the SOAP UI URL for the WSDL?  Did you use the exact same URL when generating the SOAP stubs? To see what URL your SOAP code is using, select your project and then go to the search menu, select file and in the "Containing Text" section put "@WebServiceClient", be sure the search window at bottom shows "Selected Resources" as set.

Comment: With the search results, find the service class you're calling and see if the line that starts with "url = new URL(baseUrl, "http:" is set to, it should match whats in SOAP UI

Comment: Yes i'm using the same dev machine and there is no difference between URL's in WSDL and URL that i call from my WS class "@WebServiceClient". i still got this exception : com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: erreur de transport HTTP : java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: That really shouldn't be happening then.  Is your app connecting to a public web service that I could try it out for you?  Is the web service internal to your network or even possibly located on your same dev box?  Theres a couple more -D parameters I can pass along which will help debug the situation further if you need them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182150/discussion-between-fk-net-and-jglass).

Answer (score 1):

Adding an additional troubleshooting answer.  A great way to test SSL connectivity. Source: [4ndrej awesome SSL Poke GitHUB example](https://gist.github.com/4ndrej/4547029)

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.io.*;

/** Establish a SSL connection to a host and port, writes a byte and
 * prints the response. See
 * http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Connecting+to+SSL+services
 * 
 * JGlass: Code modified for SO to hard code the host and port
 * 
 */
public class SSLPoke {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //add the full FQDN to the host here
        String host = "google.com";
        //your port may be 443
        int port = 8443;

        try {
            SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(host, port);

            InputStream in = sslsocket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = sslsocket.getOutputStream();

            // Write a test byte to get a reaction :)
            out.write(1);

            while (in.available() > 0) {
                System.out.print(in.read());
            }
            System.out.println("Successfully connected");

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If everything works correctly you'll get "Successfully Connected"